# Recursively searching an object and editing a string when found

Tags: python, string, design-patterns, recursion, immutability

I am new to python and having issues dealing with immutable strings. My problem is as follows:

I have a tree where each node is a dictionary and each node has variable number of children. I have multiple operations I wish to perform on this tree and therefore recursively traverse it.

The setup is that I have class that traverses the tree with the following function like so:

```
def __recursiveDive(self, node, enterFunc, leaveFunc, parentNode):
    if self.__break:
        return

    if not self.__skipNode:
        enterFunc(node, parentNode, self)
        if isinstance(node, dict):
            for key, value in node.items():
                self.__recursiveDive(value, enterFunc, leaveFunc, node)
        elif isinstance(node, list):
            for child in node:
                if isinstance(child, dict):
                    self.__recursiveDive(child, enterFunc, leaveFunc, node)

        leaveFunc(node, parentNode, self)
    else:
        self.__skipNode = False
```

enterFunc and leaveFunc are defined externally and perform the required work on the tree/node.

My issue is that since python strings are immutable I feel like I am unable to modify any string fields in the tree. The enterFunc, which is a function belonging to another class and is passed to the class is as follows:

```
def enter(self, node, parentNode, traverser):
    if isinstance(node, str):
        search = re.search(self.regexPattern, node)
        if search:
            node = node.replace(search.group(2),self.modifyString(search.group(2)))
```

The changes to node here are local only. Is my only solution to have the enter and leave functions return the node?

What is the correct/pythonic way to approach this problem?

### For those who want a TL;DR of the solution

Make sure your pattern returns the variable which has work done on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `enterFunc` and `leaveFunc` should return the modified object instead of attempting to modify it in-place. Then the `__recursiveDive` function can replace the original object with the returned object.

Usually you'd implement `__recursiveDive` in such a way that it it knows *both* the key and the value of a node, but that doesn't seem to be the case in your code - it gets passed a `node` variable, but not the corresponding key. It should work kind of like this (pseudo-code, obviously):

```
def __recursiveDive(self, enter, leave):
    for key, value in self.nodes:
        new_value= enter(value)
        self.nodes[key]= new_value

        if isinstance(new_value, dict):
            new_value.__recursiveDive(enter, leave)

        new_value= leave(new_value)
        self.nodes[key]= new_value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Quick question: "new_value.__recursiveDive(enter, leave)" the dictionary new_value doesn't have the member function __recursirveDive. I guess my question is how is that legal as new_value is not the same type as the class __recursiveDive belongs to.

Comment: @John Think of the type check as a sort of `if __recursiveDive should be called on this object: call __recursiveDive`. I'm not sure how exactly to implement it with your code.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes a lot more sense! For clarity's sake the data structure is pretty horrible (I have no control over this unfortunately). each leaf/node can be either a list or dictionary and they are nested, sometimes its dictionary->dictionary.... or list_element -> dictionary->list->element->dictionary->dictionary and so on.